# Site that blocks you from visiting a site too much?

Tags: limited-access

A while ago I came across a site that allows you to enter a link, e.g. facebook.com, and then it generates a link you can use to access that site. Then you can set how often you are allowed to visit that site. So, if you want to limit yourself to only visiting facebook every 3 hours, you can do that.

Anyone know the link to this site?

Comment: You're missing the computer related part of the question since this is about crowd-sourcing the use of search engines to help you find a particular site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the site you're asking about, but there's a Firefox extension called [LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476) which can do what you want - if using a firefox extension is an option.